# Problem with Mirror and Sub Modifier

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, mirror

I added a Mirror Mod and a Sub Mod to my object. After that, I got a small gap. How can I fix it?
Clipping is activated and I tried to Merge some Vertexes but it was ok. So what's the problem?

Oh and by the way, another proble to solve :). How can I get this tip round (small one in the image). When I move the Vertex, it will be round and flat. I need the arch exactly there.[image]

File:
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe you have an inner face? please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: As moonboots wrote: pls provide your blend file

Comment: @moonboots File is added

Answer (score 3):

You have inner faces along the mirror axis, remove them:

[image]

Comment: haha，you are fast..

Comment: it's BSE, you need to be the fastest  ^^

Comment: Many thanks. That solved both problems